# How to switch between users on one terminal?

Tags: login, users

I'd like to log in as a different user without logging out of the current one (on the same terminal). How do I do that?

Comment: I asked a similar question, because I ran into issues with XDG environment variables (`$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` in particular) that were driving me nuts. -> http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354826/how-to-switch-between-users-on-one-terminal-completely-xdg-environment-variab

Answer (score 875, accepted):

How about using the `su` command?

```
$ whoami
user1
$ su - user2
Password:
$ whoami
user2
$ exit
logout
```

If you want to log in as root, there's no need to specify username:

```
$ whoami
user1
$ su -
Password:
$ whoami
root
$ exit
logout
```

Generally, you can use `sudo` to launch a new shell as the user you want; the `-u` flag lets you specify the username you want:

```
$ whoami
user1
$ sudo -u user2 zsh
$ whoami
user2
```

There are more circuitous ways if you don't have sudo access, like ssh username@localhost, but `sudo` is probably simplest, provided that it's installed and you have permission to use it.

Comment: Also, `su - [user]` may be useful -- the extra dash gives you a login shell.

Comment: I am getting this error "-su: /dev/stderr: Permission denied" after executing this command `echo >>/dev/stderr` on a login with `su --login ...`, any tip? I found this btw http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38538/bash-dev-stderr-permission-denied

Comment: Does this allow each new user to have different, overriding values for environment variables? e.g. git config for work, open source, etc.

Comment: One finding, when I listed the `env` it saw that everything was in order as well as a visual inspection can go; And one thing was incorrect:  `XAUTHORITY=/home/user1/.Xauthority'.  Not sure _why_?  So X-window doesn't work by default because the protection on `~/.Xauthority` file is: `-rw-------`.  I made a copy and that let me run gedit as an experiment.

Comment: if you get "This account is currently not available": su -s /bin/bash - www-data

Comment: I am slightly off the topic, but mentioning this in case you or someone else can use it. Assuming that you are using a modern OS and have tmux installed (or can install it), one way would be to:

1. Login to the host.
2. Launch a tmux or screen session.
3. Split the pane or open one or more windows as needed.
4. Sudo as the other user as mentioned by others here.
5. Switch back and forth between the users. You need not logout of any session to switch users.

Please lookup tmux for shortcuts that can help you save a lot of time.HTH.

Comment: Worth noting: while `sudo -u user …` works fine on Archlnux, however on Ubuntu 18.04. It gives the wrong home directory, e.g. `echo ~` gives root dir for me. Using `su - user` works fine however.

Answer (score 67):

Generally you use `sudo` to launch a new shell as the user you want; the `-u` flag lets you specify the username you want:

```
[mrozekma@etudes-1 ~] % whoami
mrozekma
[mrozekma@etudes-1 ~] % sudo -u nobody zsh
[nobody@etudes-1 ~] % whoami
nobody
```

There are more circuitous ways if you don't have sudo access, like `ssh username@localhost`, but I think `sudo` is probably simplest if it's installed and you have permission to use it

Comment: What if my system has neither ssh server or sudo? Can you mention that portion on the answer?

Comment: ok, Pratt answered that one

Comment: `sudo -s` gives you a shell like `su`, `sudo -i` simulates login like `su -`.  Can be combined with `-u $user`, of course.

Comment: much more efficient. being able to "login" as a user who can't normally login is a great asset..! totally allowed me to run a database instance without messing with permissions or selinux

Answer (score 38):

```
$ whoami
```

This command prints the current user. To change users, we will have to use this command (followed by the user's password):

```
$ su secondUser
Password:
```

After entering the correct password, you will be logged in as the specified user (which you can check by rerunning `whoami`.

Comment: Useful if you're not sudoer.

Comment: Better to real test of password (avoid sudo) or behavior of a new user.

Answer (score 34):

If you're running Ubuntu, and if the user you want to login as doesn't have a password set:

```
sudo su - username
```

Enter your own password and you should be set. Of course, this requires that your user has rights to gain root privileges with `sudo`.

Answer (score 12):

To switch the terminal session to a different user, where that user can't exit back into the original user, use exec:

> $|# exec su - [username]

This will technically login the new user in a new term process, and close out the current one.  That way when the user attempts exit or Ctrl-D, the terminal will close as though that user was the one who instantiated it, i.e., the user can't exit back into the original user's term.  Kind of pointless, considering they can still just start a new terminal session and automatically be in the original user term login, but there it is.

EDIT:
For what it's worth, you can use linux vlock command in your ~/.bashrc to lock terminal sessions by default, requiring the password of the term session user to unlock.  This would somewhat prevent the aforementioned term restart under the original user context, given the term isn't instantiated using the non-default ~/.bashrc of the user, as configured.

Comment: Using exec is a good use-case when you are on an SSH-connection, and want to "hand" an existing connection to another user without the need to reconnect. I wonder if there are vulnerabilities in terms of security with regard to this.

Comment: It's a direct process fork; nothing should be inherited by the new process... except environment variables and path!  Oh, and potentially also ssh-agent.  Envars and ssh-agent keyring could be worrisome!

Answer (score 6):

`sudo -iu <your_username>` for me do the trick

Answer (score 3):

Yet another route is to launch a new shell as a different (non-root) user to run commands as that user.

```
ubuntu@aws-ip:~$ sudo -u mongodb bash          #<-- or zsh, etc... 
mongodb@aws-ip:~$ mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/configdb --fork
```

An example of this is the `mongodb` user. When deploying a sharded MongoDB cluster, all the necessary processes must run as `mongodb` and it's not necessary (or entirely convenient) to daemonize the processes using init scripts for dozens of nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Let us get this right: You are logged in as UserA and want to "login" as UserB to run some commands, but would like to come back to UserA when done. For the sake of simplicity, I assume that you want to run ls -l /tmp as UserB. If you do *not* want to leave the current shell of UserA but rather run a command as UserB and still remain logged in as UserA, you should do this:

```
su - UserB -c "ls -l /tmp"   <-- Just an example
```

This assumes you know the password for UserB. However, if you do not know UserB's password, you need to know the root password. Then:

```
sudo su - UserB -c "ls -l /tmp"   <-- UserB's pw not needed here
```

If you would rather temporarily login as UserB to run lots of commands, then just do:

```
sudo su - UserB
```

This will give you a new shell for UserB (check that by typing id). When done, you can do ctrl-d and return to your login.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run just a single command, you can use sudo:
`sudo -u username command`

Answer (score -1):

```
~$ sudo login
```

Then it will prompt you for the sudo password (the currently logged in user's password).

Also: make sure that the current user is in the sudoers file!

Comment: The question was about logging in as a different user.