# bash: /dev/stderr: Permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions, stdout

After upgrading to a new release version, my `bash` scripts start spitting errors:

```
bash: /dev/stderr: Permission denied
```

in previous versions Bash would *internally recognize* those file names (which is why this question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416)) and *do the right thing (tm)*, however, this has stopped working now. What can I do to be able to run my scripts again successfully?

I have tried adding the user running the script to the group `tty`, but this makes no difference (even after logging out and back in).

I can reproduce this on the command line without problem:

```
$ echo test > /dev/stdout
bash: /dev/stdout: Permission denied
$ echo test > /dev/stderr
bash: /dev/stderr: Permission denied
$ ls -l /dev/stdout /dev/stderr
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May 13 02:04 /dev/stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May 13 02:04 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
$ ls -lL /dev/stdout /dev/stderr
crw--w---- 1 username tty 136, 1 May 13 05:01 /dev/stderr
crw--w---- 1 username tty 136, 1 May 13 05:01 /dev/stdout
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.24(1)-release
```

On an older system (Ubuntu 10.04):

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.1.5(1)-release
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /dev/stdout /dev/stderr` and `ls -lL /dev/stdout /dev/stderr` ?

Comment: @Keith: see my edited question. Does that mean that Bash has completely abandoned the internal handling of this? On older systems these symlinks did not exist and yet the code worked without problem. Note, this is running impersonated via `sudo su username2 -` ...

Comment: What bash version are you using? `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: What are the old and new versions (before and after of your OS and of bash?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I don't think this is *entirely* a bash issue.

In a comment, you said that you saw this error after doing

```
sudo su username2
```

when logged in as `username`.  It's the `su` that's triggering the problem.

`/dev/stdout` is a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/1`, which is a symlink to, for example, `/dev/pts/1`. `/dev/pts/1`, which is a pseudoterminal, is owned by, and writable by, `username`; that ownership was granted when `username` logged in. When you `sudo su username2`, the ownership of `/dev/pts/1` doesn't change, and `username2` doesn't have write permission.

I'd argue that this is a bug.  `/dev/stdout` *should* be, in effect, an alias for the standard output stream, but here we see a situation where `echo hello` works but `echo hello > /dev/stdout` fails.

One workaround would be to make `username2` a member of group `tty`, but that would give `username2` permission to write to *any* tty, which is probably undesirable.

Another workaround would be to login to the `username2` account rather than using `su`, so that `/dev/stdout` points to a newly allocated pseudoterminal owned by `username2`.  This might not be practical.

Another workaround would be to modify your scripts so they don't refer to `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr`; for example, replace this:

```
echo OUT > /dev/stdout
echo ERR > /dev/stderr
```

by this:

```
echo OUT
echo ERR 1>&2
```

I see this on my own system, Ubuntu 12.04, with bash 4.2.24 -- even though the bash document (`info bash`) on my system says that `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` are treated specially when used in redirections.  But even if bash doesn't treat those names specially, they should still act as equivalents for the standard I/O streams.  (POSIX doesn't mention `/dev/std{in,out,err}`, so it may be difficult to argue that this is a bug.)

Looking at old versions of bash, the documentation implies that `/dev/stdout` et al are treated specially whether the files exist or not.  The feature was introduced in bash 2.04, and the `NEWS` file for that version says:

> The redirection code now handles several filenames specially:
>   /dev/fd/N, /dev/stdin, /dev/stdout, and /dev/stderr, whether or not
>   they are present in the file system.

But if you examine the source code (`redir.c`), you'll see that that special handling is enabled *only* if the symbol `HAVE_DEV_STDIN` is defined (this is determined when bash is built from source).

As far as I can tell, *no* released version of bash has made the special handling of `/dev/stdout` et al unconditional -- unless some distribution has patched it.

So another workaround (which I haven't tried) would be to grab the [bash sources](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/), modify `redir.c` to make the special `/dev/*` handling unconditional, and use your rebuilt version rather than the one that came with your system.  This is probably overkill, though.

**SUMMARY :**

Your OS, like mine, is not handling the ownership and permissions of `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` correctly.  bash *supposedly* treats these names specially in redirections, but in fact it does so only if the files don't exist.  That wouldn't matter if `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` worked correctly.  This problem only shows up when you `su` to another account or do something similar; if you simply login to an account, the permissions are correct.

Comment: The ownership of the TTY should change.  That's what ConsoleKit (a.k.a. `pam_ck_connector.so` is for).

Comment: Actually, I could be wrong.  Will have to dig more.

Comment: On my systems, `/proc/self/fd/1` is having its permissions updated, but that's pointless, since it's a symlink.  Happens on Fedora too, which seems to rule out ConsoleKit.

Comment: What about using /dev/tty instead of /dev/stdout?

Comment: @FilipStefanov `/dev/tty` and `/dev/stdout` are not the same thing, particularly if standard output has been redirected, either by the current process or by something that invoked it. If `/dev/tty` suits your purposes, by all means use it.

Comment: And yet another workaround (better than crazy stuff like giving users powers or modifying the bash source to make it even *more* broken) is a simple use of a "useless" cat  (or of `script /dev/null` if the script requires a terminal). `su -c 'echo yeah >/dev/stdout | cat'`, `su -c 'script -q /dev/null -c "echo yeah >/dev/stdout"'`.

Comment: (replace `echo yeah >/dev/stdout` with the actual script which writes to `/dev/stdout`). Analogous stuff works for `/dev/stdin` or `/dev/stderr`.

Comment: If it really is an environment problem with an `su` then would running `su -` work?  Usually that switches to the environment of the given user so maybe it would populate things better.

Comment: @davolfman A quick experiment (I still see the behavior on Ubuntu 22.04, Bash 5.2.0) indicates that using `su -` doesn't make any difference. `su -` configures some environment variables, the working directory, and `argv[0]` of the shell; it doesn't change the way `/dev/stdout` works.

Answer (score 2):

Because I wanted the same lines to go to the console (or log-file, if redirected), where the user will see them verbatim, *and* to a filter, that would parse them, I used `somecommand | tee /dev/stderr | myfilter`.

This broke, when a user attempted to run my script after `sudo`-ing...

The work-around is to check, whether `/dev/stderr` is writeable -- which it will be if

- there's been no `sudo` involved, *or*
- if the standard error is being redirected to a file

So here is, what I do:

```bsh
if [ -w /dev/stderr ]
then
        STDERR=/dev/stderr
else
        STDERR=/dev/tty # The only reason is that stderr is a link to console
fi
...
somecommand | tee $STDERR | myfilter
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the reason for this is that udev specifically sets the permissions to 0620 on tty devices and su does not change either the ownership or permissions nor should it.  In my view this leaves us in a situation that makes /dev/std* non-portable.

The simple solution is to put "mesg y" in /etc/profile (or whatever top level profile you like to use) as this changes the permissions of your tty device to 0622.  I don't really like that but it is probably better than changing the udev rules.

Comment: "msg y" doesn't work

Comment: Wait ... maybe search for *Bash handles several filenames specially when they are used in redirections* in the man page of Bash.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I think still very relevant, hence here is solution I found that is not mentioned here.

I came across this question as I also have seen issues in an 'su' switched account executing command like this in bash:

```
echo test > /dev/stderr
```

Since all I am trying to do is redirect stdout to stderr, the following achieves the same, and it works even in 'su' switched account:

```
echo test 1>&2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but to fix the problem after it happens:

```bash
sudo chown -v $USER `tty`
```

Answer (score -1):

As a long time Linux user I recently set up a new Ubuntu 64 bit 12.04 LTS system and was mystified as to why my bash scripts weren't working — permission denied — and I subsequently found this thread. I thought the problem might be due to something in the new OS.

In the end it turns out that I'd stupidly used a UI tool to set permissions on my `/home` directory, and the problem was **drive**-related. To be sure, I created a `temp` directory on `/opt` and found my scripts would run just fine from there. Once I fixed the `/home` drive permissions everything was back to normal.

One little mystery solved. *sigh*

Comment: This must have been a different error. Modifying something in /home does not affect /dev.

Answer (score -5):

This solved this problem for me:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /dev`

It obviously needs to  be run each time you `su` to another user.

Comment: This would chown *all* objects under /dev to the current user, potentially blocking any other users from writing to their /dev/std{in,out,err} .   A personal machine may not have any other human users, but will often have various service accounts in /etc/passwd.  I would not encourage this action.

Comment: This variant works: `sudo chown -v $USER $(tty)`