# LinuxLive: Howto login with local username

Tags: users, data-recovery, live-usb, non-root-user, livecd

Linux (installed on my PC) doesn't want to boot anymore. So I access my data on my hard disk by running Linux from a bootable Linux Live USB stick. But some files on my harddisk can only be read with local username. I tried to use the terminal: [su - username](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3572/184608), but it could not find this username.

So how (from my Live system) can I tell "su" to log in with the username which exists on the local harddisk? I need to do this because I forgot my email password which is locally stored by mozilla thunderbird's password manager.

Answer (score 0):

As root you should be able to read files. Anyway you can add a user with the uid you need (the one on the files).