# Same user after switch user command (su - mysql --> whoami 'old_user'), why?

Tags: users, su

I am trying to [switch the user in my shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/how-to-switch-between-users-on-one-terminal) with `su - [user]`, but the user seems to remain the old one:

```
# this works pretty well
bodo@bodo-work:~$ sudo -u mysql whoami
[sudo] password for bodo: 
mysql

# but not this
bodo@bodo-work:~$ whoami
bodo
bodo@bodo-work:~$ su - mysql
Password:

# still having 'bodo' as user seems to be wrong here 
bodo@bodo-work:~$ whoami
bodo # what?
```

Please note that there was no error message, like *could not find home directory*. What am I doing wrong here? The defined home directory of the user *mysql* belongs to it:

```
sudo ls -lah /var/lib/mysql
total 215M
drwx------  7 mysql mysql 4,0K Feb 10 14:30  .
# [...]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you `grep mysql /etc/passwd`, I reckon you will find that the shell has been set to `/sbin/nologin`. Running `sudo` gets around that and will execute `whoami` as `mysql`. That is, the `sbin/nologin` does not run because is not regarded as a login shell.

When you run `su - mysql`, you get logged back out to `bodo` straight away since `/sbin/nologin` is being called and thus `whoami` is being run by `bodo`.

When I run the `su`, I do get the error `This account is currently not available.` back which I would have thought you would have seen.

Comment: This my well be! I was not aware of the mysql user being a no-login user, too. I've thought the **mysql user bodo** is a no-login user only. But where should I see `/sbin/nologin` since I cannot see this for `grep mysql /etc/passwd` (`mysql:x:127:134:MySQL Server,,,:/var/lib/mysql/:/bin/false`). Is it `/bin/false`? I also do not get your last point: where should I run `su` for getting this message?

Comment: In your case, the shell has been set to `/bin/false` and that is always going to eject straight away, hence no `This account is cur...`. If you change the shell to `/sbin/nologin`, you will get the error message.